# How can i determine if a REST url contains HTTPS in a Delphi REST Server?

Tags: rest, delphi, url, webrequest

I would like to allow only `https` requests to my REST server. If I use `Request.ProtocolVersion` I get `HTTP/1.1` for http and https. Is there a way to get the full URL? Currently the **url** property only returns `/newspay/mcnewspay.dll`.

Comment: Are you using DataSnap?  Something else?  Need more information...

Comment: In HTTPS, the TLS handshake must be complete before the HTTP request can then be sent. If your server does not use a TLS-secured port for its connections, then it is not going to receive HTTPS requests to begin with. If your server uses a mix of non-TLS HTTP and TLS-secured HTTPS, checking which port a request is received on will suffice. A non-TLS HTTP request can't be sent to a TLS-secured HTTPS port, and vice versa. So either just shut down the non-TLS port altogether, or else reply with an HTTP redirect to all requests received on the non-TLS port to direct them to the TLS-secured port.

Comment: @J... It is a Datasnap WebBroker Application. Compiled as a dll and deployed using IIS.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: Thanks for the answer. It helped me to realise that I can get the server port from the `TWebRequest` and check if it is 443. If not, I do not authorise the request.

Comment: @PietervanWyk You can also just configure IIS (using your *.config file) to only allow transport encrypted endpoints.  And you can [redirect http requests to https in IIS](https://serverfault.com/q/893315) also.